# LDAP Query: results to dynamic DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, active-directory, ldap

I'm writing a c# method to query Active Directory and return the results as a DataTable. The method needs to take an LDAP target and an LDAP query.

Examples:

```
DataTable users = LDAPQuery("LDAP://mydomain.com", "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))")
DataTable desktops = LDAPQuery("LDAP://mydomain.com", "(&(objectCategory=computer)(name=desktop*))")
```

My attempt is below. I think I have most of it, but I want to build the DataTable dynamically based on the properties returned from the query, rather than hard coded columns as below. Can anyone show me how to do this? Or if there is a better way, using ADODB for example?

```
    protected DataTable LDAPQuery(string domain, string query)
    {
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(domain);
        DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
        ds.Filter = query;
        ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        SearchResultCollection src = ds.FindAll();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("samaccountname");
        dt.Columns.Add("givenName");
        dt.Columns.Add("sn");
        dt.Columns.Add("mail");

        foreach (SearchResult sr in src)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            DirectoryEntry de = sr.GetDirectoryEntry();
            dr["samaccountname"] = de.Properties["samaccountname"].Value.ToString();
            dr["givenName"] = de.Properties["givenName"].Value.ToString();
            dr["sn"] = de.Properties["sn"].Value.ToString();
            dr["mail"] = de.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            de.Close();
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Why on earth using a `DataTable`? Seems very "outdated". Can't you just define a `MyAdType` class to hold the properties you're interested in, and return a `List<MyAdType>` instead of a clunky old `DataTable` with lots of relational overhead that you don't need??

Comment: Also: if you're on .NET 3.5 or higher, check out [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) - read [this excellent MSDN article on it first!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)

Comment: I want to load the results into a database so a DataTable suits me.

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the reference to the excellent article. Exactly what the doctor prescribed. ++

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a great idea since your database schema should match the datatable fairly well. But if you insist, DirectoryEntry.Properties.PropertyNames has all the names that you can loop through. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.propertycollection.propertynames.aspx